# swift json: one key in user defaults - two structs

Tags: json, swift, userdefaults

I want to save data to UserDefaults using one key. Then we check - if entry is 'Task' then write toDo in TableViewCell; if 'Project' then let user move to another TableViewController to see all tasks. Please help with coding/decoding...

```
protocol UserEntry: Codable {}

struct Task: UserEntry, Codable {
    var toDo: String
}

struct Project: UserEntry, Codable {
    var name: String
    var tasks: [Task]
}

var userEntries: [UserEntry] {
    get {
        guard let encodedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "userEntry"), let decodedData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([UserEntry].self, from: encodedData) else { return [] }
        return decodedData
    }
    set {
        guard let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) else { return }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encodedData, forKey: "userEntry")
    }
}

userEntries.append(Task(toDo: "write a letter"))
userEntries.append(Project(name: "Make a dinner", tasks: [Task(toDo: "buy food"), Task(toDo: "cook food")]))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use **one** struct `Project` where an empty (or even optional) `tasks` array indicates *ToDo*?

Comment: I'm not looking for simple solutions :)